# Chrome DevTools slow when debugging javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I've noticed that whenever I'm trying to debug my javascript in DevTools on Chrome, DevTools slows down a lot, so that when I type into the console, there is a noticeable lag. This happens even if the js file is just a few lines.

I have disabled source mapping in DevTools, which seemed to help a little bit, but DevTools is still slow, particularly when I'm pausing on exceptions or using debugger or breakpoints.

This could very well be normal behaviour, but I just wanted to check since I'm new to this.

Comment: I think there've been a bunch of performance issues recently. I find Chrome Canary is a bit faster.

Comment: Same problem for me on both stable release (v52)  and Canary release (v54)